# UIButton title changes while moving in UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am quit new in iOS and working on a project while moving in a UITable next time comes back my UIButton that is an array changes while i am passing same Array to UILabel as well as UIButton but button title is not working properly.
code snipt is as below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIImageView *imageV;
    UILabel *labelV;
    UILabel *labelU;
    UIButton *buttonA;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
        imageV.tag = 1001;
        imageV.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5,30, 30 );

        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageV];

        labelV = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        labelV.tag = 1051;
        labelV.frame = CGRectMake(120, 5,135, 15 );
        labelV.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:labelV];

        labelU = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        labelU.tag = 1052;
        labelU.frame = CGRectMake(120, 25,135, 15 );
        labelU.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:labelU];

        buttonA = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        buttonA.frame=CGRectMake(250, 10, 50, 25);
        buttonA.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:buttonA];
    }

    else
    {
      imageV = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];
      labelV = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1051];
      labelU = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1052];
    }

    imageV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    labelV.text = [salesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    labelU.text = [priceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    buttonA.tag=indexPath.row;

    [buttonA addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   // if()
    [buttonA setTitle:[salesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:23.00/255.00 green:65.00/255.00 blue:74.00/255.00 alpha:1.00];

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple. Just think logically.

A table view only has a few cells, maybe 10 or 20 at most. Even if it has lots of *rows* it only needs a few cells, because when cells are scrolled off the screen they are reused for a row that is being scrolled onto the screen.

Okay, so...

Suppose this cell is being reused. Then it is not nil after the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Are you with me so far?

Then the whole section about `if (cell == nil)` is *skipped* because the cell is *not* nil. Do you understand?

So now what is `buttonA`? It is nil! Why? Because the code that created the button and assigned that button to `buttonA` was skipped.

So when you finally get to this line:

```
[buttonA setTitle:[salesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

... you are talking to nil and nothing happens.